# Javascript unpack command line dictionary

Tags: javascript, node.js, minimist

I am learning javascript.

I am recieving a variable length of dictionary from the command line of the form

```
--myargs = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}
```

I can read the args by

```
var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv)
var myargs = argv["myargs"]
```

I need to unpack the dictionary `myargs` like this->

```
my_new_args= {Key: "foo", Value: "bar", Key: "foo2", Value: "bar2" };
```

How do I do this in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` on object keys and return array of objects.

```js
var myargs = {"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}
var result = Object.keys(myargs).map(e => ({Key: e, Value: myargs[e]}));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You're welcome, note that you cant have same keys in object

Comment: Yeah, that confused me, the result he wants in `my_new_args` is actually illegal Javascript. Fair play for figuring out what OP probably really wanted.

Comment: I actually have another bug in my code,  `var argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));
console.dir(argv)
var myargs = argv["myargs"] ` is not returning `{"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}` but its returning `{`

Comment: @Illusionist What is it returning then?

Comment: Its returning just `{` , I am trying to pass `--tags={"foo":"bar", "foo2":"bar2"}`  . I tried escape charactesr and wrapping the dict in quotes

Comment: I never used that package but i think your input should look like this `node yourFile.js -foo bar -foo2 bar2`